# If sets have same number of elements $r$ and the intersection of any $r+1$ of them is empty then there is a system of distinct representatives (Hall?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $(A_1, ..., A_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise distinct nonempty finite sets. Prove that if all sets $A_i$ have the same number of elements $r$ and the intersection of any $r+1$ of them is empty (more precisely, that: $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i \in T} A_i = \emptyset$ for every  ($r+1$)-element set $T \subseteq [n]$), then the sequence $(A_1, ..., A_n)$ has a system of distinct representatives.

---

I thought that it can be solved using Halls theorem: a collection $ \{A_1,A_2,...,A_n \}$ of $n$ nonempty finite sets has a system of distinct representatives if and only if, for each integer $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, the union of any $k$ of these sets contains at least $k$ elements.

But I don't know what to do, any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you know what do do: you have to show that, for any nonempty set $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ you have $|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i|\ge|I|$.

Let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ and let $P=\{(i,x):i\in I,\ x\in A_i\}\subseteq I\times X$.

Since each $A_i$ has $r$ elements, $|P|=r|I|$. On the other hand, since each point $x\in X$ belongs to at most $r$ of the sets $A_i$, $|P|\le r|X|$. So $r|I|=|P|\le r|X|$; since $r\gt0$ it follows that $|X|\ge|I|$.

Comment: Great, thank you!